# Index not updating in Dynamic View Arrangement example

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I read about the [dynamically re-arrange-able view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html). Same is available as an example in the Qt-Creator as well.

I wanted to store back this updated rearranged order in my database. I added an extra line to the column definition for checking the index values :

```
     Column {
                id: column
                anchors { fill: parent; margins: 2 }

                Text { text: 'Name: ' + name }
                Text { text: 'Type: ' + type }
                Text { text: 'Age: ' + age }
                Text { text: 'Size: ' + size }
                Text { text: 'Rank: ' + index } // Added to test the index values
            }
```

However, I realize that after re-arranging the elements, the index value is showing as same in the UI. Is it that index doesn't change ? Or the binding of the text is not working properly and updated index value is not showing up after rearrangement ?

Before:

[image]

After moving the top most element (Polly) a little down:

[image]

The way I understand it, Ranks should always show up from 0 to highest value, as we move from top to bottom, irrespective of the rearrangement, because the index values will be in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is the `index` you display in your delegate is the original index in the `PetModel`. To convince you of this, you just have to slightly modify the example.

```
PetsModel {
    id: petsModel
}

DelegateModel {
    id: visualModel
    model: petsModel
    delegate: dragDelegate
}

...

ListView {
    id: view
    anchors { fill: parent; margins: 2; rightMargin: parent.width/2+2 }
    model: visualModel
    spacing: 4
}

ListView {
    id: view2
    anchors { fill: parent; margins: 2; leftMargin: parent.width/2+2  }
    model: petsModel
    delegate:dragDelegate
    spacing: 4

}
```

You'll see that no matter how you move the items around in `view`, the actual items order in `view2` remains the same.

The `DelegateModel` acts as a proxy to the actual PetModel (kind of like [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html))

If you want to display the proxy index, use the attached [`dragArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#itemsIndex-attached-prop) property

```
Column {
    id: column
    anchors { fill: parent; margins: 2 }

    Text { text: 'Name: ' + name }
    Text { text: 'Type: ' + type }
    Text { text: 'Age: ' + age }
    Text { text: 'Size: ' + size }
    Text { text: 'Index: ' + index }
    Text { text: 'Display Index: ' + dragArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex }
}
```